# "Table or view does not exist" on synonym

Tags: oracle, errors

I have a database and a USER administrating it. Then I have an additional USER_APP to whom I granted CRUD access to all tables in my oracle data modeler (and then applied these via generated script )

I created a synonym for every table from USER_APP account, with the following syntax:

```
create synonym USER_APP.CLIENTS for USER.CLIENTS;
```

And for every table generation is successful and commit made.
But when I try to use it anyhow on that account, for example:

```
select * from CLIENTS;
```

I get an error that CLIENTS do not exist, namely

```
ORA-00942 : table or view does not exist.
```

What can I do to fix that or where should I look to determine the cause/solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Synonyms have nothing to do with privileges.  They are simply a way to simplify naming.

The error you are getting appears to indicate that `user_app` does not have privileges on the `user.clients` table.  You'd need to grant that

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
   ON user.clients
   TO user_app;
```

Of course, in your actual system, I'm guessing that there is a role that you would grant privileges to and that role would be granted to `user_app`.